# Get all input value in a array from a jquery dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a dynamic table using jquery as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        data     : data,
        type     : "get",
        url      : url,
        dataType : "json",
        error    : function(resp){
                    alert("Error !!");
        },              
        success  : function(resp){
                    table = '';
                    $.each(resp,function(indx,obj){ 
                    table += '<tr>';
                    table += '<td>'+parseInt(indx+1)+'</td>';
                    table += '<td>'+'<input type="text" value="'+obj.ServiceDetail.service_code+'">'+'</td>';
                    table += '<td>'+'<input type="text" value="'+obj.ServiceDetail.name+'">'+'</td>';
                    table += '<td>'+'<input type="text" value="'+obj.ServicePrice.discount_price+'">'+'</td>';
                    table += '</tr>';                                           
                    });
                    $("tbody#sevice_table_body").append(table);
        }    
});
```

and a button :

```
 <input type="button" class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" value="submit" >
```

now i want to get all input value in a array by click submit button so that can be inserted in a database table using jquery ajax.

Comment: And what is the problem? If you wrap them in a form, you can serialize the form on submit

Comment: no i want to save using jquery ajax

Comment: Yes `$("#formID").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(): $.ajax( .... data: $(this).serialize() .... } ) `

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for cycling the input and add them to an array

```
var arrayOfVar = []
$.each($("input[type='text']"),function(indx,obj){
    arrayOfVar.push($(obj).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)  it Encode elements as an array of names and values.

Find below fiddle for more info

```js
$(function() {
  var data = $("#tbl2 :input").serializeArray(); // For converting it to array
  //If needed below code is converting it to object
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;
  }
  console.log(data); // Print Array in Console
  console.log(obj);// Print Object in Console
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl2">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tb3" value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tb4" value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tb5" value="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tb6" value="4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute name with name and array .

```
$.ajax({
            data     : data,
            type     : "get",
            url      : url,
            dataType : "json",
            error    : function(resp){
                        alert("Error !!");
            },              
            success  : function(resp){
                        table = '';
                        $.each(resp,function(indx,obj){ 
                        table += '<tr>';
                        table += '<td>'+parseInt(indx+1)+'</td>';
                        table += '<td>'+'<input type="text" name="service_code[]" value="'+obj.ServiceDetail.service_code+'">'+'</td>';
                        table += '<td>'+'<input type="text" name="name[]"  value="'+obj.ServiceDetail.name+'">'+'</td>';
                        table += '<td>'+'<input type="text" name="discount_price[]"  value="'+obj.ServicePrice.discount_price+'">'+'</td>';
                        table += '</tr>';                                           
                        });
                        $("tbody#sevice_table_body").append(table);
            }    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var inputData = [];

$('button[value="submit"]').click(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]).each(function(){
    inputData.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your table section, add name attribute like this:

```
$.each(resp,function(indx,obj){ 
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>'+parseInt(indx+1)+'</td>';
    table += '<td>'+'<input name="services[' + indx + '][code]" type="text" value="'+obj.ServiceDetail.service_code+'">'+'</td>';
    table += '<td>'+'<input name="services[' + indx + '][name]" type="text" value="'+obj.ServiceDetail.name+'">'+'</td>';
    table += '<td>'+'<input name="services[' + indx + '][price]" type="text" name="service[' + indx + '][price]" value="'+obj.ServicePrice.discount_price+'">'+'</td>';
    table += '</tr>';                                           
});
```

This will produce names like `services[0][code]`, `services[0][name]`, etc.,

Now you can access the input values as an array in PHP:

```
$services = $_POST['services'];
foreach ($services as $index => $service) {
    $code  = $service['code'];
    $name  = $service['name'];
    $price = $service['price'];

    echo "$index : $code, $name, $price \n";
}
```